# Problemas em salvar no banco em projeto Spring MVC

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc

Eu sou novo como desenvolvedor em Spring MVC, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples, porém bem diferentes do que usualmente criando, porque geralmente o FrameWorks Spring MVC usa arquivos de XML para configurar o projeto, e eu estou usando a classe Java para fazer essas coisa, inclusive dispensei o arquivo XML que é persistences.xml e conetando através de classe java como você podem ver abaixo;

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {
      @Bean
       public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
          em.setDataSource(dataSource);
          em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "br.com.casadocodigo.loja.models" });

          JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
          em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
          em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

          return em;
       }

       @Bean       
       public DataSource dataSource(Environment environment){
          DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
          dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/casadocodigo");
          dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
          dataSource.setPassword( "123" );
          return dataSource;
       }

       @Bean
       public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
          JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);     
          return transactionManager;
       }

       @Bean
       public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }

      Properties additionalProperties() {
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
          return properties;
       }
}
```

Para configurar o projeto utilizei essa classe ;

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={HomeController.class, ProductDAO.class})
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

}
```

Essa é minha classe controller que da tabela produto;

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import br.com.casadocodigo.loja.daos.ProductDAO;
import br.com.casadocodigo.loja.models.Product;

@Controller
@Transactional
public class ProductsController {

@Autowired
private ProductDAO productDAO;

@RequestMapping("/produtos/")
public String save(Product product){
    productDAO.save(product);
    return "products/ok";
}

@RequestMapping("/produtos/form")
public String form(){
    return "products/form";
}


}
```

E essa é minha pagina;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cadastro de Produtos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" >

        <div>
            <label for="title">Titulo</label> <input type="text" name="title"
                id="title" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="description">Descrição</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="description" id="description"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pages">Número de Paginas</label>
            <input type="text" name="pages" id="pages"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
        </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Esta carregando perfeitamento, consigo visualizar a pagina, porém eu coloco os dados na pagina e clico enviar e não consegue salvar os dados no banco, e também não gera mensagem de erro no eclipse.

Aonde será que estou errando no projeto?

Será que é o action que está na pagina  form.jsp?

como funciona o vinculo do botão enviar com o método que salvar?

Comment: Alguma exceção? Algum erro no console do servidor?

Comment: nada tu acredita!

Comment: https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja meu projeto completo.

Comment: tem algum lugar do código que eu pudesse dá system.print.out para ver o que está dentro de entrada e saida  da variavel?

Comment: Cara, dá uma pesquisada em como adicionar o log4j no seu projeto e setá-lo como debug, assim você vai ver tudo que está acontecendo no log do servidor.